# Autosys Job box kicking off without meeting its starting conditions

Tags: autosys

I am running into a problem while designing a solution using autosys. Looking for some inputs on this scenario:

I have three job Boxes viz. BoxA,BoxB and BoxC.

BoxA has two jobs inside it A1 and A2 respectively and I have configured the last job in this box with two exit codes as  success codes 0 and 10 respectively.
Now depending upon the exit code of the job in this box, I want to trigger either BoxB( if exit code is 0 ) or BoxC( if exit code is 10 ).

Additional information for BoxB and BoxC:

BoxB has 5 jobs in it names B1,B2...B5 and this box will kick off when exit code of A2 will be 0.

BoxC has 7 jobs in it and this box will kick off if either A2 exits with code 10 OR B5 goes into success.

ISSUE description:
If A2 exits with code 10 then in that case the solution is working as expected amd BoxC gets kicked off.
However, if A2 exits with code 0 both BoxB and BoxC get kock off.

This is the starting condition of BoxC:
(e(A2)=10) or s(B5)

Please advise.

Comment: I am still looking for some inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Harsh,

As stated, jobs are A1 A2 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7.
All jobs are under one box alone.

**CASE I:   Assuming the box start at 01:00 hours and job A2’s exit code is 0**

```
insert_job: BOX_NAME    
job_type: box
owner: ##
max_run_alarm: 0
alarm_if_fail: n
date_conditions: y
start_times: "01:00"
run_calendar: ##
send_notification: n
box_success: s(C7)
```

A1  Success

A2  Success with E=0

Job B1 defined as

```
insert_job: JOB_B1
condition: e(A2)=0
```

B1      Success

B2 .. B5    Success

Job C1 defined as

```
insert_job: JOB_C1 
condition: e(A2)=10 | s(B5)
```

C1 .. C7    Success

box completed !!

**CASE II: job A2’s exit code is 10**

A1  Success

A2  Success with E=10

condition: e(A2)=0  *#jobs remains activated*

B1 .. B5    Activated

condition: e(A2)=10 | s(B5) *# OR condition is fulfilled C1 starts*

C1 .. C7    Success

B1 .. B5 jobs remain activated but box completes upon success of C7.

box completed !!

Hope this helps.

Let me know if i am clear enough.

My answer is considering only the happy cases and not into account of the extreme cases.